# Vim wrong indentation

Tags: ruby, vim

I am using Vim for editing Ruby files **on Windows 7** and I have a problem with indentation. On my Ubuntu virtual machine, **with the same Vim settings**, the indentation for Ruby files is correctly set to 2 characters. I didn't have to specify `expandtab` or setting tabs width.

My _vimrc/.vimrc file is just sourcing the default vimrc_example file and the `filetype plugin indent` is set to `on`.

This is what I get on Windows:

[image]

If I type `:filetype` I get the following result:

```
filetype detection:ON plugin:ON indent:ON
```

If I type `:set filetype?` I get the following result:

```
filetype=ruby
```

If I type `:set indentexpr?` I get the following result:

```
indentexpr=GetRubyIndent()
```

P.S. I have the same problem with PHP.

Comment: No. The simple fact that you have different tab sizes proves that you *don't* have the same settings on both machines. What is the version (with patch level) of Vim on both machines? Why `_vimrc/.vimrc` instead of `_vimrc`? What is the output of `:verbose set tabstop` and `:verbose set shiftwidth`?

Comment: @romainl The culprit was the vim-rails plugin which was setting the expandtab option. Thank you so much for the :verbose option! If only I had known this before! +1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I have the answer!
I temporarily renamed all the plugin folders on my Ubuntu until I found the culprit!
The excellent [vim-rails](https://github.com/tpope/vim-rails) plugin is also setting expandtab and shiftwidth for you :)
Now I just have to install it on Windows too.

Comment: I just want to add that from version 5.0 the indentation settings are no longer automatically applied (http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1567): "Indent settings are no longer automatically adjusted.  Try sleuth.vim."

Answer (score 3):

To set the indentation for just one type of files, use `autocmd` by placing the following in your `~/.vimrc` file (or for windows `_vimrc`).

```
autocmd BufNewFile,BufRead *.ruby set shiftwidth=2
autocmd BufNewFile,BufRead *.ruby set tabstop=2
autocmd BufNewFile,BufRead *.ruby set softtabstop=2
```

Or to do the same thing the cleaner way, place a `ruby.vim` file inside of `~/.vim/ftplugin/` with the following inside of it:

```
set tabstop=2  
set softtabstop=2 
set shiftwidth=2
```